# Не приходит письмо на почту после регистрации пользователя

Tags: php

Пытаюсь настроить регистрацию на сайте, но не приходит письмо на почту с ссылкой на активацию после регистрации пользователя, данные в БД добавляются, но письма нет
Файл registration.php

```
$server_bot = 'smtp.мояпочтаgmail.com';
            $password_bot = 'пассотпочты';
            $mail_bot = 'no-reply@mysite.com';
            $name_bot = 'site';
            $title = 'Confirmation of registration on mysite';
            $mess = 'In order to continue registration, click on the link:';
            $mess1 = 'If you did not register on this site, then just ignore this email.';
            //SETTINGS//

            //
            include_once('db_connect.php');
            include_once('inc.class.php');//Различные классы и функции для упрощения работы

            $SETTINGS = new SETTINGS();
            $FORM = new FORM();
            $AUTH = new AUTH();

            // Присваивание переменных из предыдущей формы
            $password1 = "passwordlength16";
            $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
            $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
            $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
            $tm = time();
            $password = openssl_encrypt($password,"AES-128-ECB",$password1);



            $querylogin=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE login='".$login."'");
            $numrowlogin = $querylogin->num_rows;


            $queryemail=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE mail='".$mail."'");
            $numrowemail = $queryemail->num_rows;


            //Всё для бота отправки сообщ
            $mail_class = new EMAIL($email_bot); //Создаём экземпляр класса
            $mail_class->setFromName($name_bot); //Устанавливаем имя в обратном адресеc
            $mailSMTP = new SMTP_EMAIL($server_bot, $mail_bot, $password_bot, $name_bot, 25); // создаем экземпляр класса
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
            $headers .= "From: ".$name_bot." <".$mail_bot." >\r\n"; // от кого письмо
```

Вспомогательный файл inc.class.php, где прописан класс SMTP_EMAIL

```
class SMTP_EMAIL {

    public $smtp_username;
    public $smtp_password;
    public $smtp_host;
    public $smtp_from;
    public $smtp_port;
    public $smtp_charset;

    public function __construct($smtp_host, $smtp_username, $smtp_password, $smtp_from, $smtp_port = 465, $smtp_charset = "utf-8") {
        $this->smtp_username = $smtp_username;
        $this->smtp_password = $smtp_password;
        $this->smtp_host = $smtp_host;
        $this->smtp_from = $smtp_from;
        $this->smtp_port = $smtp_port;
        $this->smtp_charset = $smtp_charset;
    }

    function send($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers) {
        $contentMail = "Date: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " UT\r\n";
        $contentMail .= 'Subject: =?' . $this->smtp_charset . '?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . "=?=\r\n";
        $contentMail .= $headers . "\r\n";
        $contentMail .= $message . "\r\n";
        try {
            if(!$socket = @fsockopen($this->smtp_host, $this->smtp_port, $errorNumber, $errorDescription, 30)){
                throw new Exception($errorNumber.".".$errorDescription);
            }
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "220")){
                throw new Exception('Connection error');
            }
            fputs($socket, "EHLO " . $this->smtp_host . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: HELO');
            }
            fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error1');
            }
            fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "334")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error2');
            }
            fputs($socket, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "235")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Autorization error3');
            }
            fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM: ".$this->smtp_username."\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: MAIL FROM');
            }
            fputs($socket, "RCPT TO: " . $mailTo . "\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: RCPT TO');
            }
            fputs($socket, "DATA\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "354")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception('Error of command sending: DATA');
            }
            fputs($socket, $contentMail."\r\n.\r\n");
            if (!$this->_parseServer($socket, "250")) {
                fclose($socket);
                throw new Exception("E-mail didn't sent");
            }
            fputs($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
            fclose($socket);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
        return true;
    }
    private function _parseServer($socket, $response) {
        while (@substr($responseServer, 3, 1) != ' ') {
            if (!($responseServer = fgets($socket, 256))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
            if (!(substr($responseServer, 0, 3) == $response)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
}
```

Может кто-нибудь помочь разобраться?

Comment: почему бы не воспользоваться общеизвестной библиотекой, а не городить свои костыли? Там и исключения выпадают, если что не так идёт

Comment: @ArchDemon а посоветовать можете библу?

Comment: @ArchDemon вы имели ввиду phpmailer?

Comment: Я пользовался swiftmailer/swiftmailer и zendframework/zend-mail